# When trying to output image to browser using PHP imgpng, I get a broken image

Tags: php, html, image, gd

This is the code that presents the form which will pass on the uploaded picture to the process_image.php:

```
This form allows you to upload a file to the server.<br>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="process_file.php" method="POST"><br>
     Type (or select) Filename: <input type="file" name="uploadFile"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File">
</form>
```

and this is the php that is supposed to process that image and show it:

```
<?php

    header( "Content-Type: image/png" );
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"]);
    imagepng($im);

?>
```

However when I run this all I get on the second page is a broken image.

Comment: Your form `action` attribute is set to `process_file.php`, not `process_image.php`. Also, you are probably not in the temporary directory with your action page. Fix the URL in `imagecreatefrompng()`.

Comment: What's the rest of process_file.php contain?  If you have any other information being shown/displayed, you could get the broken image.

Answer (score 0):

Try use echo var_dump($_FILES) and see if all the data is there and that there is no error message.